# Attaching formControlName directive to a component created programatically

Tags: angular

I've a library custom form components built in Angular 7. Each of this component is wrapper over native `input`, `textarea`, `checkbox` elements. I've implemented the ValueAccessor to make them work with `ngModel` and `formControl`/`formControlName`. Things works fine in the case of declarative use.

for ex.

```
<custom-textbox label="Name" required formControlName="name"></custom-textbox>
```

In my use-case, I've to create the custom form components dynamically from JSON and I've used ComponentFactoryResolver to accomplish that. My problem is when I create these custom form components dynamically how I can apply the `formControlName` directive to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Like any other Angular input, `[formControlName]="myOjbect.nameLabel"`

Comment: We need to apply that to the host element so the above idea won't work.

Comment: Don't see why, and you didn't specify that. Please provide a [mcve] if you want a thorough and adapted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your JSON looks like...

```ts
myJson = [
  {
    ctrl: 'field1'
  },
  {
    ctrl: 'field2'
  }
];
```

We build our form by iterating the fields in the array:

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({})

this.myJson.forEach(x => {
  this.myForm.addControl(x.ctrl, this.fb.control(''));
});
```

Then we can use the `keyvalue` pipe provided by angular to iterate the form controls and pass the form control with `ctrl.key`

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div *ngFor="let ctrl of myForm.controls | keyvalue">
    <my-field [formControlName]="ctrl.key"></my-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

Another option, is to skip the component, and go fully for a dynamic form: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

This should get you started, hopefully it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is even `my-field` component itself created dynamically like the link you shared. So, i've no idea how we can apply `formControlName`.

Comment: Well, this is kind of what can happen when not providing an [mcve] You won't get answers that applies to your usecase ;) Please create a stackblitz showcasing this issue and I'd be happy to take a look.